# Can I make the lock screen image span two monitors?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, lock-screen

I've got my desktop background spanning two displays, and I want the lock screen to show the same thing. Can I set the lock screen to span just like the desktop?

Comment: ... and with more displays this becomes more relevant... !!!